What does the first colon mean in the ":b:" with getopt command line?
Show bash and getopt version in my OS:
bash --version |grep [r]elease
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
getopt --version
getopt from util-linux 2.38.1

In the getopt's manual(man getopt's PARSING part),it says that "A simple short option is a '-' followed by a short option character. If the option has a required argument, it may be written directly after the option character or as the next parameter (i.e., separated by whitespace on the command line). If the option has an optional argument, it must be written directly after the option character if present."
vim  test.sh
arg="b is B by default"
TEMP=$(getopt -o b::  -- "$@")
eval set -- "$TEMP"
while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -b)
            arg="$2"
            shift 2;;
        --)
            shift 
            break;;    
    esac
done
echo "$arg"

Show behavior of option -b :
bash  test.sh 
b is B by default
bash  test.sh -bc
b is c
bash  test.sh -b c
b is 

bash  test.sh -b c output b is ,it comply with the rule:If the option has an optional argument, it must be written directly after the option character if present.
Now i rewrite getopt -o b::  -- "$@" into getopt -o :b:  -- "$@".
vim  test.sh
arg="b is B by default"
TEMP=$(getopt -o :b:  -- "$@")
eval set -- "$TEMP"
while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -b)
            arg="$2"
            shift 2;;
        --)
            shift 
            break;;    
    esac
done
echo "$arg"

Show behavior of option -b :
bash  test.sh 
b is B by default
bash  test.sh -bc
b is c
bash  test.sh -b c
b is c

Why getopt -o :b:  -- "$@" can make bash  test.sh -b c output b is c?:b: break the default rule,what does the first colon mean in :b:?How getopt parse the :b:?

Try calling your script with an unexpected argument like -x with and without the leading : in your getopt string (:b: vs b:) and you'll see that without it you get an error message getopt: unknown option -- x. See @Shawn's answer for why.

You have to dig into the man page for the getopt(3) function to get the full behavior of the optstring.
For the b:::

Two colons mean an option takes an optional arg; if there is text in the current argv-element (i.e., in the same word as the option name itself, for example, "-oarg"), then it is returned in optarg, otherwise optarg is set to zero.  This is a GNU extension.

As you note, that's why you get a blank argument for -b c; the c is a different word and not used as the argument.
For the leading colon:

If the first character (following any optional '+' or '-' described above) of optstring is a colon (':'), then getopt() likewise does not print an error message.  In addition, it returns ':' instead of '?' to indicate a missing option argument.  This allows the caller to distinguish the two different types of errors.

In your example you don't do anything to trigger the special behavior of the leading colon. It does demonstrate the behavior of a single colon after the option letter, though (which indicates a required argument).

If such a character is followed by a [single] colon, the option requires an argument, so getopt() places a pointer to the following text in the same argv-element, or the text of the following argv-element, in optarg.


Ugh, that’s kind of horrible. My mental model is that -oarg is equivalent to -o arg and that works in the vast majority of cases…this is enabling behaviour that explicitly goes against that norm.

@nneonneo I don't think the optional argument thing is used very often.
